# How to search for patterns with curly braces using sed in Tcl

Tags: linux, sed, tcl

Example: input file is like below

```
 signal {   
    XX, yy,
    Zz 
    XX ck" {
        P { 10ps
            25ps
            100ps }
    }
    yy ck" {
        P { 10ps
            25ps
            100ps }
        }
    Zz ck" {
        P { 10ps
            25ps
            100ps }
        }
    "XX"+, "yy"+, "zz"
}
```

The output I need is,

```
   signal {    
        XX, yy,
        Zz 
        "XX"+, "yy"+, "zz"
    }
```

Above example is part of lines in a file, I should use the sed command to remove the pattern having curly brace till 6 lines in tcl.

used below command,

exec /bin/sed -e {xx ck" { /, +6d} -i file

its not working , its deleting other line also
 should delete  below things,

```
       Zz ck" {
            P { 10ps
                25ps
                100ps }
            }
       XX ck" {
            P { 10ps
                25ps
                100ps }
          }
       yy ck" {
            P { 10ps
                25ps
                100ps}
            }
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the desired result when using double-quotes (`"..."`) to escape the sed expression instead of using curly braces (`{...}`):

```
exec /bin/sed -e "/.. ck\" \{/,+4d" -i file
```

Note that I've also changed the expression to delete only 4 lines.

Comment: I'd be _terrified_ to hard-code the rules to delete a fixed number of lines like that. The chance of things going really badly wrong when real input data is used is just too large.

Comment: Totally agreed. But that's not the OP's question. BTW, calling `sed` from TCL is already kind of strange...

Comment: thankyou its working. i have one more query, in my file i have Zz ck" {
            P { 10ps
                25ps
                100ps }
            } Zz ck" {
            Data { 10ps
                100ps }
            } abcdef.. I should delete both of the expression if i try to delete the by using this expression exec /bin/sed -e "/.. ck\" \{/,+4d"  it will deleted the second expression also with next lines but i should not